# Filter NULL value in dataframe column of spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe(df) with following:

```
+---------+--------------------+
|  col1|        col2           |
+---------+--------------------+
|colvalue1|                NULL|   
|colvalue2|col2value...        |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to filter rows based on the col2 as follows

```
df.filter(($"col2".isNotNULL) || ($"col2" !== "NULL")  || ($"col2" !== "null")  || ($"col2".trim !== "NULL"))
```

But the row which has NULL is not filtering. This column show `nullable=true`.

Can anyone let me know what mistake I am doing? I am using Spark 1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `!==` notation is wrong which should be `=!=`, and you can't do `$"col2".trim` and **since you have used negations with `||`, one of the negation is always true**. In your example `($"col2".isNotNULL)` is always true so every rows are filtered-in. So individual negation combined by `||` should be taken with care.

So the correct form is

```
df.filter(!($"col2".isNull || ($"col2" === "NULL") || ($"col2" === "null")))
```

or even better if you use inbuilt function `isnull` and `trim`

```
df.filter(!(isnull($"col2") || (trim($"col2") === "NULL") || (trim($"col2") === "null")))
```

Comment: was this (trim($"col2") === "null") necessary? Should spark catalist be case insensitive?